# iOS location manager update more often then once in a second

Tags: ios, swift, location, core-location, cllocationmanager

I created location manager with

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
```

but location updates received once per second.
Is it possible to get updates more often?

I tried to get current location in timer, but it's still updated once per second.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

```
[self pingLocation];//viewDidLoad

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    manager.delegate = nil;
    self.currentLocation = (CLLocation *)[locations lastObject];

}

- (void) pingLocation {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self performSelector:@selector(pingLocation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];//change to whatever you want
}
```

This seemed to give me fairly good results and could make it update more than once per second.  However, it drains battery very drastically and is not the best practice.  I would ask yourself: why do you want this?  Do you really need more than one update per second?

Edit: I've just tested this again and I believe that although it appears to update every half second, it doesn't really.  For example:

30.00000, 60.00000

30.00000, 60.00000

30.00032, 60.00056

30.00032, 60.00056

Thus, you really can't update faster than a second, sorry to say.

Comment: Unfortunately looks like you are right. I recreated test with a timer -- same results. Tried to ask manager for current location more often, not wating for update -- same. Which seems strange approach since, on a high speeds location could change dramatically.
My goal was to measure host distance like 10 meters, so time interval mattered.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `CLLocation.startUpdatingLocation` documentation:

> Calling this method several times in succession does not automatically
>   result in new events being generated. Calling `stopUpdatingLocation` in
>   between, however, does cause a new initial event to be sent the next
>   time you call this method.

You will probably have to also set `distanceFilter` to none. However, you can imagine these two will help churn through a battery.

Comment: unfortunately looks like, it doesn't update location itself, I tried that as well as in answer below and it just sends same location multiple times. Only thing I didn't try is to set `distanceFilter` to none, since it's not possible: just not to set it at all.

Comment: By saying 'none', I didn't mean not setting it, I meant setting it to none - `kCLDistanceFilterNone`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

By this, location manage get update more often. Because every time when it get update it will request for another location frequently.